# Subtract 1 letter and number from multiple strings of letters and numbers

Tags: r, vector, gsub

I have a vector of character strings:

```
grid_loc <- c("B2", "B3", "B4", "C2", "C3", "C4", "D2", "D3", "D4")
```

How can I recode these strings so the new vector looks like this?:

```
c("A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B3", "C1", "C2", "C3")
```

As you can see, I would like each letter&number string to have "one" subtracted from it. `B` becomes `A`, `3` becomes `2` etc.

In the original dataset there are no strings containing the letter `A` or the number `1`, so figuring out what to do with this situation isn't an issue.

I attempted to use `gsub()` to manually recode each string but due to the size of the real dataset this is too laborious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are no 'A's or 1's in the original vector, then one option is to use `gsubfn` to subtract the number and replace the letter with the letter before it

```
library(gsubfn)
f1 <- function(x, y) paste0(LETTERS[match(x, LETTERS)-1], as.numeric(y) - 1)
gsubfn('([A-Z])([0-9]+)', f1, grid_loc)
#[1] "A1"  "A2"  "A3"  "B1"  "B2"  "B3"  "C1"  "C2"  "C3"  "A19"
```

#### data

```
grid_loc <- c("B2", "B3", "B4", "C2", "C3", "C4", "D2", "D3", "D4", "B20")
```

Comment: This almost works perfectly, the only problem is when I have `B20` for example, it's replaced with `A10`, rather than `A19`.

Comment: Apologies, I hadn't thought about the larger numbers in the string, only the `A1` problem.

Comment: @JohnGodlee  It is a simple fix.  `[0-9]` to `[0-9]+`.  Updated the post

Comment: Amazing, you are amazing. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

Another way, using `base R` can be to `split` each element after the letter with `strsplit`, compute the "minus 1" operation on each part and repaste them:

```
sapply(strsplit(c(grid_loc, "B20"), "(?<=[B-Z])", perl=TRUE), 
       function(x) paste0(LETTERS[match(x[1], LETTERS)-1], as.numeric(x[2])-1))
#  [1] "A1"  "A2"  "A3"  "B1"  "B2"  "B3"  "C1"  "C2"  "C3"  "A19"
```

Answer (score 0):

HERE is purely base R way:

```
fun=function(x){paste0(LETTERS[match(sub("[^A-Z]+","",x),LETTERS)-1],
              as.numeric(sub("\\D+","",x))-1)}
fun(x)
 [1] "A1"  "A2"  "A3"  "B1"  "B2"  "B3"  "C1"  "C2"  "C3"  "A19"
```

data

```
x=c("B2", "B3", "B4", "C2", "C3", "C4", "D2", "D3", "D4", "B20")
```